# Docbook formatting email addresses

Tags: docbook

I am trying to get some documentation up and running; however, my email address is not coming up as linkable:

```
<email><ulink url="mailto:SomeUser@someDomain.com"/></email>
```

Becomes:

```
<mailto:SomeUser@someDomain.com>
```

I don't want the mailto: to appear.  If I put content in the ulink, it shows the mailto and the content whereas I would just want the content to appear.

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Tync said, Docbook itself does not specify formatting.  When you write the `<email>` tag, that merely indicates to the *renderer* that the enclosed text is an email address.  The renderer may then decide that it should be formatted `as monospace text`, or maybe that your email should be ***bold and italics***!

Likewise, there's a lot of tags that are pretty meaningless as far as formatting goes -- [the city tag](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/city.html), for instance.  But, that is metadata to the document that might be important to some Docbook parser out there.

The only way to *guarantee* that your email is a hyperlink to sending you an email is to use the [`ulink`](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/ulink.html) tag as you have shown above, because a renderer *must* create a hyperlink if the output format supports it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I just need to figure out how to hide the mailto: stuff from displaying and I will be golden.


If you know what attribute that might be under, that will help out a lot.


Thanks,
Walter

Answer (score 2):

Docbook is subspace of XML and does not specify any formatting: these rules are described in XSL or DSSSL scripts that convert the mark-up into a formatted text. I believe you should check these rules out!

Comment: I have a rule that works for links to web pages, but I'm not having such luck with email addresses.

Which way is correct though <email> or <ulink url="mailto: ...">?


Walter

Comment: Sorry, i have no experience with DocBook :) I just know it separates model from view, so you sould look there...

Answer (score 1):

The right way to specify email addresses is with the email tag: <email>user@example.org</email>.

The DocBook XSL stylesheets, and I'd expect most other systems, render that as a mailto: link when generating HTML.

Comment: Ok, I think I tried that at some point, but still had issues with what it displayed / was formatted like.  Would you be able to help with the XSL to?